# Select Field in Phoenix Templates

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I know `Phoenix` provides some nice Railsy helpers that can be used in forms like:

- `text_input`
- `number_input`
- `date_select`
- and `submit`

but I can't find one for `select` fields. I've been searching the [Phoenix Docs](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/), but couldn't find anything.

*So my question is, is there a Phoenix `helper` for select fields in forms?*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I should've been searching the [`Phoenix.HTML`](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/) Docs (Thanks to [José](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30965683/1533054) for pointing this out!)

**The helper for `select` is:**

> [select(form, field, values, opts \\ [])](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#select/4)

---

#### Examples:

```ex
# Assuming form contains a User model
select(form, :age, 0..120)
#=> <select id="user_age" name="user[age]">
#   <option value="0">0</option>
#   ...
#   <option value="120">120</option>
#   </select>

select(form, :role, ["Admin": "admin", "User": "user"])
#=> <select id="user_role" name="user[role]">
#   <option value="admin">Admin</option>
#   <option value="user">User</option>
#   </select>

select(form, :role, ["Admin": "admin", "User": "user"], prompt: "Choose your role")
#=> <select id="user_role" name="user[role]">
#   <option value="">Choose your role</option>
#   <option value="admin">Admin</option>
#   <option value="user">User</option>
#   </select>
```

Comment: Can anyone confirm that passing key: value pairs to the select function actually works? I'm on the latest version of Phoenix.HTML and am getting an error: `protocol String.Chars not implemented for {:Foo, "#229de8"}`
Works fine if I just pass it a normal list of single values.

Comment: Try String keys instead of Atoms

Comment: I was, I have tried both ways. That error is generated from
<%= select f, :color, ["Foo": "#229de8"] >

Comment: @BrandonHoward This is working for me in Phoenix 1.2.1, Phoenix.HTML 2.9.3 : `<%= select f, :color, ["Col1": "#229de8", "Col2": "#228de3"] %>`

Comment: @BrandonHoward `types = Repo.all(Type) |> Enum.map(&{&1.title, &1.id})` this works for me

Answer (score 10):

It is there, the docs are in the Phoenix.HTML project: http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/